# Why a selector is returning me a string instead the data requested?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

I have a selector that return an array value of a state in some reducer, but instead of the data it returns me a string of the function.

This is the way it SHOULD work

```
export const selCurrentLanguage = createSelector([getLanguage], language => language)
```

I expect this result: language: 'ES'

This is what I get in the console.log:

```
state => state.configurationGeneralReducer.language
```

Here's a snapshot of what I got in console:

[image]

Comment: I was able to get the data by using this method:  export const selCurrentLanguage = createSelector(
    state => state.ConfigGeneralReducer.language,
    (language) => language
)

Comment: I want to know why the first doesn't work... i acept whatever you give to me in answer to this... thanks

Comment: What does the `getLanguage` function look like? To debug the original code, that would be helpful.

Comment: Can you show what your mapStateToProps looks like so we can see how you invoke the selector?